# Grouping rows to conversations and add conversation number

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a file which has messages between customers and agents but these message are not grouped by conversations i.e. there is unique conversation id. Luckily the original message is included in each following reply to that message. The message is in the 'text' column. This can be easily explained by below example

```
actionDateTime      text         response                    postTime

2019-01-01 12:00    Hi           N/A                         2019-01-01 12:00
2019-01-01 12:01    Hi           Hello!                      2019-01-01 12:00
2019-01-01 12:02    Hi           How can I help?             2019-01-01 12:00
.
.
.
2019-01-02 12:00    Hi there      N/A                        2019-01-01 12:00
2019-01-02 12:01    Hi there      Morning                    2019-01-01 12:00
2019-01-02 12:02    Hi there      How can I help?            2019-01-01 12:00
```

So I tried the code below to group but this isn't working.

```
df %>%
group_by(text, postTime) %>%
mutate(convID = row_number()) %>%
ungroup()
```

This does output a file with convID but not the way I want. In fact, I don't understand how's it numbering. I believe that's because I'm using two variables in group_by. However, using only one will not work as two different people can message at the same time or two different messages can look similar (e.g. a lot of people can start with just 'Hi').

When I tried only group 'text' it still gives me numbers within a conversation rather than a unique ID. Again, explained below

What I get

```
text         response                    postTime           convID

Hi           N/A                         2019-01-01 12:00   1
Hi           Hello!                      2019-01-01 12:00   2
Hi           How can I help?             2019-01-01 12:00   3
.
.
.
Hi there      N/A                        2019-01-01 12:00   1
Hi there      Morning                    2019-01-01 12:00   2
Hi there      How can I help?            2019-01-01 12:00   3
```

What I want:

```
text         response                    postTime           convID

Hi           N/A                         2019-01-01 12:00   1
Hi           Hello!                      2019-01-01 12:00   1
Hi           How can I help?             2019-01-01 12:00   1
.
.
.
Hi there      N/A                        2019-01-01 12:00   2
Hi there      Morning                    2019-01-01 12:00   2
Hi there      How can I help?            2019-01-01 12:00   2
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need `group_indices`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(convID = group_indices(., text, postTime))
#    actionDateTime     text        response         postTime convID
#1 2019-01-01 12:00       Hi             N/A 2019-01-01 12:00      1
#2 2019-01-01 12:01       Hi          Hello! 2019-01-01 12:00      1
#3 2019-01-01 12:02       Hi How can I help? 2019-01-01 12:00      1
#4 2019-01-02 12:00 Hi there             N/A 2019-01-01 12:00      2
#5 2019-01-02 12:01 Hi there         Morning 2019-01-01 12:00      2
#6 2019-01-02 12:02 Hi there How can I help? 2019-01-01 12:00      2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(actionDateTime = c("2019-01-01 12:00", "2019-01-01 12:01", 
"2019-01-01 12:02", "2019-01-02 12:00", "2019-01-02 12:01", "2019-01-02 12:02"
), text = c("Hi", "Hi", "Hi", "Hi there", "Hi there", "Hi there"
), response = c("N/A", "Hello!", "How can I help?", "N/A", "Morning", 
"How can I help?"), postTime = c("2019-01-01 12:00", "2019-01-01 12:00", 
"2019-01-01 12:00", "2019-01-01 12:00", "2019-01-01 12:00", "2019-01-01 12:00"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```